# Query - Why standardsetcontroller page is not visible in Lightning Page Tabs?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience, tab

I have created one standardsetcontroller VF page to show list of record and this page should be open in lightning tab.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [Visualforce Tab](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_tabs_create.htm&type=5) that references the Visualforce page and that tab should appear in the "All Items" list of the App Launcher.